# Change border color if tr hasClass

Tags: jquery, css

I am trying to change border color of 1st `<td>` inside a table / `<tr>` if the 2nd `<td>` is complete by having the class of `.wcpv-order-status-completed`

On a page with a couple of `<tr>` how can I target only the ones that have order-status-completed?

Tried with jQuery and PHP if-statement

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("tr:has(.wcpv-order-status-completed)").css("border", "solid green");
});
```

Each  is setup like this. 2nd td will change either being wcpv-order-status-completed or processing:

```
<tr>
   <th scope="row" class="check-column"><input type="checkbox" name="ids[6]" value="5"></th>
   <td class="order_id column-order_id has-row-actions column-primary" data-colname="Booking"><a href="https://example.com/wp-admin/12" class="wcpv-vendor-order-by-id">1528</a><button type="button" class="toggle-row"><span class="screen-reader-text">Vis for flere detaljer</span></button></td>
   <td class="order_status column-order_status" data-colname="Booking status"><span class="wcpv-order-status-completed">Gennemført</span></td>
   <td class="order_date column-order_date" data-colname="Booking dato">June 5, 2019 9:19 am</td>
   <td class="shipping_address column-shipping_address" data-colname="Shipping"></td>
   <td class="product_name column-product_name" data-colname="Product"><a class="post-edit-link" href="https://example.com/admin/123"</a></td>
   <td class="total_commission_amount column-total_commission_amount" data-colname="Commission"><span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount">350&nbsp;<span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">DKK</span></span></td>
   <td class="commission_status column-commission_status" data-colname="Kommission Status"><span class="wcpv-unpaid-status">UBETALT</span></td>
   <td class="paid_date column-paid_date" data-colname="Paid Date">0000-00-00 00:00:00</td>
   <td class="fulfillment_status column-fulfillment_status" data-colname="Udførselsstatus"><span class="wcpv-fulfilled-status">Opfyldt</span></td>
</tr>
```

I am trying to have the border on the 1st `<td>` which has selector: `.vendor td.order_id a`

However, the selector above will affect all of the `<tr>`s

I expect border color change to green if order status is completed.

Comment: If the `<tr>` that you're selecting will be the one with the class, you can just use `$("tr.wcpv-order-status-completed")`, i.e. _"Select any `<tr>` that has class `wcpv-order-status-completed`"_. Then again, if you're looking for *a `<tr>` that **contains an element** with class `wcpv-order-status-completed`*, that'd be a case for `:has()`.

Comment: Assuming the `tr` has a class of `.wpcv...` `$("tr.wcpv-order-status-completed)").css("border", "1px solid green");`

Comment: After editing your question I see that the HTML tags you included had originally gotten lost (parsed). It seems that you want the `<tr>` border to change if it contains a `<td>` with a specific class. Given that realization, this *would* be a case for `:has()`, though your code looks fine. Please provide a [**minimal, reproducible example**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of the issue (i.e., add your HTML). 
Do you see the style applied to your `<tr>` if you inspect it?

Comment: Do you have `border-collapse: collapse` applied to the table? Table row borders won't show otherwise.

Comment: Why don’t you use css class styling for it? Why are you using javascript? If you do like that, you may miss some elements if you are running that code to early

Comment: @Fetz CSS doesn't have a supported `:has()` selector equivalent. You can't style a parent element conditionally based on its children.

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/hasClass/ `hasClass`

Comment: @demo That doesn't seem applicable here as it requires you to target a *specific* element, as opposed to *"Check for the presence of class `X` anywhere within element `Y`"*

Comment: but has is only check if tr has that class, and it’s applying to tr. And by the way set the border size to at least 1px

Comment: The row you included in your question contains some syntax errors. You have an unclosed `href` and `<a>` tag in the `product_name` column.

Comment: @Fetz *"has is only check if tr has that class"* - This is incorrect. See [`:has()`](https://api.jquery.com/has-selector/): *"Selects elements which **contain** at least one element that matches the specified selector. The expression `$( "div:has(p)" )` matches a `<div>` if a `<p>` exists anywhere among its descendants"*

Comment: OP, please [**see here**](https://jsfiddle.net/xna2two9/). I've copy+pasted your code, and it doesn't reproduce the issue. As mentioned above, make sure you have `table { border-collapse: collapse }` applied, otherwise your `<tr>` will never show a border. Your question must include enough code to reproduce the issue that you're describing. Also,  you edited and added this line: *"I am trying to have the border on the 1st `<td>` which has selector: `.vendor td.order_id a`"* but it seems like a completely different question...? It's not very clear.

Comment: @Tyler Roper Thank you! Sorry for not being clear enough... I want to change border of 1st td if the 2nd td is completed. In your example is the border around the whole tr

The selector I guess I am supposed to target is .vendor td.order_id a - However, this is global and will affect all of the <tr> and not only the ones that is completed as I am trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can slightly modify your `:has()` selector:

```
$("tr:has(.wcpv-order-status-completed) td.order_id a").css("border", "solid green");
```

This will find a `<tr>` that has a `.wcpv-order-status-completed`. Within that `<tr>`, give the `order_id` link a green border.

That said, for max efficiency, break it into pieces.

```
$("tr").has(".wcpv-order-status-completed").find("td.order_id a").css("border", "solid green");
```

Per [the documentation](https://api.jquery.com/has-selector/):

> Because `:has()` is a jQuery extension and not part of the CSS specification, queries using `:has()` cannot take advantage of the performance boost provided by the native DOM `querySelectorAll()` method. **For better performance in modern browsers, use `$( "your-pure-css-selector" ).has( selector/DOMElement )` instead.**

Added to your code, it looks like this:

```js
$("tr").has(".wcpv-order-status-completed").find("td.order_id a").css("border", "solid green");
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <th scope="row" class="check-column"><input type="checkbox" name="ids[6]" value="5"></th>
    <td class="order_id column-order_id has-row-actions column-primary" data-colname="Booking"><a href="https://example.com/wp-admin/12" class="wcpv-vendor-order-by-id">1528</a><button type="button" class="toggle-row"><span class="screen-reader-text">Vis for flere detaljer</span></button></td>
    <td class="order_status column-order_status" data-colname="Booking status"><span class="wcpv-order-status-completed">COMPLETED</span></td>
    <td class="order_date column-order_date" data-colname="Booking dato">June 5, 2019 9:19 am</td>
    <td class="shipping_address column-shipping_address" data-colname="Shipping"></td>
    <td class="product_name column-product_name" data-colname="Product">
      <a class="post-edit-link" href="https://example.com/admin/123"></a>
    </td>
    <td class="total_commission_amount column-total_commission_amount" data-colname="Commission"><span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount">350&nbsp;<span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">DKK</span></span>
    </td>
    <td class="commission_status column-commission_status" data-colname="Kommission Status"><span class="wcpv-unpaid-status">UBETALT</span></td>
    <td class="paid_date column-paid_date" data-colname="Paid Date">0000-00-00 00:00:00</td>
    <td class="fulfillment_status column-fulfillment_status" data-colname="Udførselsstatus"><span class="wcpv-fulfilled-status">Opfyldt</span></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th scope="row" class="check-column"><input type="checkbox" name="ids[6]" value="5"></th>
    <td class="order_id column-order_id has-row-actions column-primary" data-colname="Booking"><a href="https://example.com/wp-admin/12" class="wcpv-vendor-order-by-id">1528</a><button type="button" class="toggle-row"><span class="screen-reader-text">Vis for flere detaljer</span></button></td>
    <td class="order_status column-order_status" data-colname="Booking status"><span class="">NOT COMPLETED</span></td>
    <td class="order_date column-order_date" data-colname="Booking dato">June 5, 2019 9:19 am</td>
    <td class="shipping_address column-shipping_address" data-colname="Shipping"></td>
    <td class="product_name column-product_name" data-colname="Product">
      <a class="post-edit-link" href="https://example.com/admin/123"></a>
    </td>
    <td class="total_commission_amount column-total_commission_amount" data-colname="Commission"><span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount">350&nbsp;<span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">DKK</span></span>
    </td>
    <td class="commission_status column-commission_status" data-colname="Kommission Status"><span class="wcpv-unpaid-status">UBETALT</span></td>
    <td class="paid_date column-paid_date" data-colname="Paid Date">0000-00-00 00:00:00</td>
    <td class="fulfillment_status column-fulfillment_status" data-colname="Udførselsstatus"><span class="wcpv-fulfilled-status">Opfyldt</span></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

I created a page with tr tags where some second td tags have the class you mentioned while others don't. At the end, there is a button that makes the validation of which tags has the class.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <meta charset = "UTF-8" />
  <title>Teste</title>
  <style>
   td {
    width: 100px;
    text-align: center;
   }
  </style>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 </head>
 
 <body>
  <table>
   <tr>
    <td>1st TD</td>
    <td class = "wcpv-order-status-completed">2nd TD</td>
   </tr>
   
   <tr>
    <td>1st TD</td>
    <td>2nd TD</td>
   </tr>
   
   <tr>
    <td>1st TD</td>
    <td>2nd TD</td>
   </tr>
   
   <tr>
    <td>1st TD</td>
    <td class = "wcpv-order-status-completed">2nd TD</td>
   </tr>
   
   <tr>
    <td>1st TD</td>
    <td class = "wcpv-order-status-completed">2nd TD</td>
   </tr>
  </table>
  
  <button>Test</button>
  
  <script type = "text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function() {
    $("button").click(function() {
     $("tr").each(function() {
      if ($(this).find("td").eq(1).hasClass("wcpv-order-status-completed")) {
       $(this).find("td").eq(0).css("border", "1px solid green");
      }
     });
    });
   });
  </script>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Apparently, you edited your question while I was creating the answer. I hope my answer helps somehow.

Comment: And don't forget you need to set border-width as, at least, 1px  :)

Comment: ^ That's actually not entirely necessary :)

Answer (score 0):

> 1st `<td>` inside a `<tr>`

Select first `td` inside `tr`:

```
highLightIfCompleted($table( {
  var $rows = $('tr');
  $rows.each(function(i,e) {
    var $row = $(e);
    var $firstTd = $row.find('td:eq(1)');
  });
}
```

> if the 2nd `<td>` is complete by having the class of `.wcpv-order-status-completed`

Check the second TD:

```
highLightIfCompleted($table( {
  var $rows = $('tr');
  $rows.each(function(i,e) {
    var $row = $(e);
    var $firstTd = $row.find('td:eq(0)');
    var $secondTd = $row.find('td.eq(1)');
    if ($secondTd.hasClass('wcpv-order-status-completed') {
      $secondTd.css("border", "solid green");
    }
  });
}
```

Example

```js
function highLightIfCompleted() {
  var $rows = $('tr');
  $rows.each(function(i,e) {
    var $row = $(e);
    var $firstTd = $row.find('td:eq(0)');
    var $secondTd = $row.find('td:eq(1)');
    if ($secondTd.hasClass('wcpv-order-status-completed')) {
      $firstTd.css("border", "solid green");
    }
  });
}

setTimeout(highLightIfCompleted, 5000);
```

```css
.wcpv-order-status-completed {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Row 1 Cell 1</td>
    <td>Row 1 Cell 2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Row 1 Cell 1</td>
    <td class="wcpv-order-status-completed">Row 1 Cell 2</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I'm curious as to why the check is in a `setTimeout()`? But also, I feel like the use of `each` to find elements by index is a bit overkill. `:has()` aside, you could just use selectors like `nth-child()`, `td:first`, etc.

Comment: @TylerRoper the question is not clear if it's the first TD in EACH row or the first TD in any row.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the boarder color of the first `<td>` of a `<tr>` which has other `<td>` elements with a specific class.

```
$('tr').each((i, raw) => {

    $(raw).children('td.wcpv-order-status-completed').length > 0
       $(raw).children('td').first().css('background-color', 'red');

  });
```